# What are the best practices when building a multi step form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, multi-step

I'm looking to learn how to implement multi step forms (wizards) with Rails 3

what are your recommended resources for it ?
any useful gems or tutorials ?

Comment: Your title says you want `best-practices`, while your question says you want `recommended resources`.  Please pick one and modify the other to match.

Answer (score 1):

watch [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) on the subject :)

Comment: I've seen it but I'm looking for other ways of implementation